# Best way to scan for and eliminate earlier versions of SSL/TLS in a production environment

Tags: tls, openssl, pci-dss

Due to new PCI DSS standards mandating that nothing lower than TLS 1.2 be used in a PCI environment, I am tasked with phasing out anything lower than TLS 1.2 on every device in this environment by our next audit next year.

**Question:**

What would be the best method of maneuvering through the environment and seeing which devices are still using deprecated versions of SSL? I know that I can use OpenSSL s_client to perform handshakes on machines, but is there a way to automate this or perhaps do this against multiple machines instead of going through a list and trying to perform a handshake against every single system? There are quite a lot of machines in this environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@atdre points to a tool that should allow detecting whether a given server *supports* TLS 1.2, but this is only part of the story. In SSL/TLS, the initial steps of a connection are the *handshake* in which a number of parameters are agreed upon between client and server, including the protocol version that will be used. The client announces the highest protocol version that it supports, then the server chooses the version that will be used (normally, the highest version that the server knows, but no higher than the maximum version announced by the client).

Therefore, even if all your servers are ready to use TLS 1.2, this does not necessarily imply that only TLS 1.2 will be used; it depends on what the servers would accept besides TLS 1.2, and what the *clients* support. For a given server, you have basically two methods to ascertain that TLS 1.2 will be used:

1. Make sure that the server supports *only* TLS 1.2: if a client announces "TLS 1.1" as highest version, the server should reject it. If a server accepts only TLS 1.2, then only TLS 1.2 will be used when talking with this server.
2. Check that all clients that talk to the server announce TLS 1.2 as highest version, and the server accepts. This basically entails running a network monitor tool (e.g. [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)) to observe the `ClientHello` messages actually sent by clients, and the `ServerHello` messages sent in response.

---

Further complications come from the "auto downgrade" behaviour of some clients (typically Web browsers). The client may try to connect, first, by sending a `ClientHello` that says "I support up to TLS 1.2". If that fails, though, the client may think that the server might be allergic to TLS 1.2 -- it is known that there are still a few deployed Web server that do not follow the specification properly, and simply drop connections when they see "TLS 1.2" because they do not understand it. In order to support these poorly implemented servers, some SSL/TLS clients, upon a handshake failure, will try again, this time with a `ClientHello` that announces "I support up to TLS 1.0".

Unfortunately (for your present situation), this means that even though a client and server seem to use TLS 1.2 under normal conditions, an active attacker may abruptly break connections that begin with a TLS 1.2 handshake (the active attacker injects spurious RST packets to kill the underlying TCP connection). In such a situation, the attacker may trigger the auto-downgrade mechanism, and force client and server to use a lower version.

So if you really want to make sure that only TLS 1.2 is ever used, even in the presence of a crafty attacker, then only the first method should apply. In other words, using `sslyze` or any other similar tool, you must make sure that when a client asks for TLS 1.2, it obtains TLS 1.2, AND also that if a client asks for TLS 1.1, the server rejects it.

Comment: great info, thanks for the parts about TLS 1.2 downgrade attacks

Comment: Note that modern browsers will include the `TLS_DOWNGRADE_SCSV` in their cipher suite in response to a downgrade attack; but it is not widely used for non-browser programs.

Answer (score 3):

Active assessment of all known IP addresses and hostnames is the best method to audit an infrastructure to full compliance.

```
sslyze --sslv2 --sslv3 --tlsv1 --tlsv1_1 --targets_in=target-list.txt --xml_out=sslyze.xml
```

You can get sslyze here -- https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/sslyze

You may also need a developer who understands XML parsing in order to best sort the results.

What do you mean by "is there a way to automate ... instead of going through a list"? Wouldn't automation require a list?

I can think of two potential ways to perform a test without connecting to each server. One would be to use a gold-standard configuration and verify it with a tool such as Lynis.  You can see a script that will check web servers for their configurations (including a detailed SSL/TLS check for nginx) here -- https://github.com/CISOfy/lynis/blob/master/include/tests_webservers

The final way to detect services in your environment that run non-compliant SSL/TLS versions would be to utilize a packet capture infrastructure. There are numerous ways to configure your environment for network capture assessments, and I won't go into them here. However, I have seen some tools which check either the server headers (which may provide an SSL/TLS library or module version) and/or the protocols themselves. In the former category: snort, prads, and tshark may be great ways to interact with live capture interfaces and/or stored pcap data. In the latter category: ssldump and pyshark can be made to provide detailed protocol information. Both of these techniques, however, will only be able to show SSL/TLS services that are in-use; they will not show dormant SSL/TLS services that are not in use, or not commonly in use. Another huge win here is [tls-fingerprinting](https://github.com/LeeBrotherston/tls-fingerprinting/) (e.g., fingerprintls) and associated [snort rules](https://github.com/LeeBrotherston/snort).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I worded the part about the automation poorly. What I meant is I didn't want to use something like OpenSSL s_client and try it over and over on multiple systems. Let me check out the SSLYZE script and see if that does what I want. Sounds like it'll work well. I don't think I'll be utilizing any pcap stuff in the environment for this particular project.